# Stop vibration in Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I use a simple Javascript to draw on canvas, script is [sketch.js](http://d1835mevib0k1p.cloudfront.net/sketch/r/71/sketch.min.js),
you can [try here](http://sketchtoy.com/)

Problem is all the lines drawn, vibrating continuously by default,

How can I stop this stupid feature?

Comment: Hm... put Vibration:0 see up menu :) Dont know why people downvote this question if it is clear and specific.

Comment: If I remove all values from vibration, after refresh will generate a '1' value and is vibrating.

Comment: Also if you embed the code somewhere? That is a canvas generator. But you can generate the code without vibration I guess.

Comment: Yes I have code on my pc

Comment: Try to find `vibrationDropdown.setValue(1)` in the code and change it to `vibrationDropdown.setValue(0)`

Comment: When I use setValue(0) generate html with 0 value, but still vibrate

Comment: I feel it is not normal behaviour, same that having vibration 1 as default value. Have you tried some other generators? Free draw: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~noam/c-generator.html
If you are used to vectors: http://www.victoriakirst.com/beziertool/